# Download File with WebClient class occurs to exception

Tags: c#, maven, webclient

As I am new to c# I can't understand why this not work.

I am trying to download files from maven repo (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)

Here is my code :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            try
            {
                var wcl = new WebClient();
                wcl.DownloadFile("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.3/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar", "C:/minecraft_test/mcassets/libraries/test/test.file");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
        }
```

I got the exception :
Receive an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.

I tries to change/remove the line :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

but I got still same error.

I tried with pwoershell :

```
$webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient;
$webclient.DownloadFile("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/takari/maven-wrapper/0.5.5/maven-wrapper-0.5.5.jar", "C:/minecraft_test/mcassets/libraries/test/test.jar");
```

and it's work...

What can I do to fix this?

Best regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.

It seems that WebClient is deprecated. In .net doc :
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8)

We can read this :

> Important
>
> We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new
> development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class.
>
> So I changed my code to use HttpClient class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, there is a problem with your 2nd parameter in

`wcl.DownloadFile("https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.3/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar", "C:/minecraft_test/mcassets/libraries/test/test.file");`.

Try to remove '.file' in the path, i am sure it will solve the problem.

Also you don't need to use following piece of code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Comment: Hi, no I need to specified a file name with extension to register the downloaded file. Please not I can download file on ftp (with credential) or other website (even without credential)
`wcl.DownloadFile("ftp://waws-prod-par-005.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/files/minecraft.jar", "C:/minecraft_test/mcassets/libraries/test/test.file");`

or

`wcl.DownloadFile("https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2794/forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2794-universal.jar", "C:/minecraft_test/mcassets/libraries/test/test.file");`